# Failed to connect to: localhost:27017: Connection refused to MongoDB database using AMPPS

Tags: mongodb, localhost, database-connection, ubuntu-14.04, ampps

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 with AMPPS for my localserver, I've managed to enable mongoDB extenstion and I've created database and collections in rockmongo and even by using terminal using mongo.

But when I'm trying to use mongodb in my code I get the below error message :

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoConnectionException' with message 'Failed to connect to: localhost:27017: Connection refused' in /usr/local/ampps/www/TMongo.php on line 3
( ! ) MongoConnectionException: Failed to connect to: localhost:27017: Connection refused in /usr/local/ampps/www/TMongo.php on line 3
```

This is the peace of code I've tried to test mongodb :

```
<?php
   // connect to mongodb
   $m = new MongoClient();
   echo "Connection to database successfully";

   // select a database
   $db = $m->laravel;
   echo "Database mydb selected";
   $collection = $db->laravel;
   echo "Collection selected succsessfully";

   $cursor = $collection->find();
   // iterate cursor to display title of documents

   foreach ($cursor as $document) {
      echo $document["title"] . "\n";
   }
?>
```

I've searched and tried a few methods to kill all mongodb process and start it again and ... but none of them worked for me.

when I run : `ps -eF | grep 'mongo\|PID'`
I get :

```
UID        PID  PPID  C    SZ   RSS PSR STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root      3516  3331  0 223796 118188 3 12:42 pts/22   00:00:01 /usr/local/ampps/mongodb/bin/mongod --journal --pidfilepath=/usr/local/ampps/mongodb/data/pid --config=/usr/local/ampps/mongodb/mongo.conf
server    7091 25150  0  2939  2280   2 12:47 pts/26   00:00:00 grep --color=auto mongo\|PID
```

when I run: `sudo killall -15 mongod` And again i run above command I get :

```
UID        PID  PPID  C    SZ   RSS PSR STIME TTY          TIME CMD
server    8299 25150  0  2939  2268   3 12:49 pts/26   00:00:00 grep --color=auto mongo\|PID
```

When I run this command while my mongodb service is off : `sudo netstat -tlnp | grep 27017`
I get nothing but when I start mongodb service and again I run netstat command I get :

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27017           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9956/mongod
```

mongodb.conf :

```
#Turn on simple rest api
rest=true

journal=true

#Storage Engine Set to mmapv1
storageEngine=mmapv1

#Directory for Data Files
dbpath={$path}/mongodb/data/db

#log file to send write to instead of stdout - has to be a file, not directory
logpath={$path}/mongodb/logs/mongo.log

#Append to logpath instead of over-writing
logappend=true

#Specify port number
#port=27017

#Full path to pidfile (if not set, no pidfile is created)
pidfilepath={$path}/mongodb/data/pid

#Each database will be stored in a separate directory
directoryperdb=true

#Run "{$path}/mongodb/bin/mongod.exe" --help in command prompt for more help.
```

FYI : I've installed ampps in it's default path for linux : /usr/local/ampps/

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 with AMPPS 3.6 for localserver. 
How can I fix this, Any suggestion ?

---

**UPDATE**
I've added this parameter to mongodb.conf file and restarted mongodb

```
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
```

Then i run this : `sudo netstat -tlnp | grep 27017`

Seems that mongodb is listening on `127.0.0.1:27017` And when I try to connect to it from command line using mongo, it works but in php page I still have the same problem.

any suggestion ?

Comment: Can you connect from the command line ?

Comment: yes, when I run mongo I can connect and run my commands

Comment: Maby a right problem, does you php have access to the mongo repertory ?

Comment: how can I check that ?

Comment: If public has read write on the repertory where where you store the db (dbpath)

Comment: @AyrtonDumas I've updated the post above - you can see mongodb.conf - and dbpath is in it

Comment: ```/mongodb/data/db``` -> ```chmod 755 -R``` ?

Comment: @AyrtonDumas I give it the permission but still nothing changed.

Comment: no more ideas sorry :(

Comment: @AyrtonDumas thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ampps 3.6 they added mongodb.so to the list of php extentions.
And if you enable mongo and mongodb extentions you will be connected to mongodb.